# Analytic continuation of double factorial

Tags: functions

This question is somewhat informative. In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) the definition of double factorial continued in the complex arguments is provided
$$
k!!=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}2^{\frac{k}{2}}\Gamma[k/2+1]
$$
Clearly, this definition does not work for positive even numbers. Is there any double factorial formula in terms of Gamma functions which works for both odd and even?

Comment: What type of properties do you want?  There's no uniqueness property to these types of expressions, so there are a lot of ways to get an expression that equals $k!!$ for all non-negative integers.  I'm not sure why you're wanting it though.

Comment: I need it from physics point of view. This is when in dimensional regularization, we take $k=d-\epsilon$ , where $\epsilon \in \mathbb{C}$, I am encountering double factorial of $k$. To evaluate it, in terms of series with respect to $\epsilon$, it is necessary to convert it into Gamma functions. In that sense, I need a consistent formula, like $n!=\Gamma[n+1]$

Comment: I've written an answer for the question you've asked, but I don't think it's the question you need to ask.  Unfortunately, other than saying "this works but it's probably not what you wanted", I can't comment on whether the function you want exists because I don't know the additional requirements from the physics context.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would get a double factorial to be honest.  Are you sure there isn't one with just Gamma functions (e.g. the volume of balls)?

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $k \geq 0$ even, we have
$$k!! = 2^{k/2} (k/2)! = 2^{k/2} \Gamma(k/2+1)$$
so that the difference only appears in the coefficient.

To generate the coefficient, it suffices to note that $\sin^2(k\pi/2)$ generates the sequence $0,1,0,1,\ldots$, so that your answer is
$$\left(1 + \left(\sqrt{2/\pi}-1\right)\sin^2(k\pi/2)\right)2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2+1)$$

---

Does this generate $k!!$ for every non-negative integer $k$?  Yes.  We can check this.

Does it have the properties that you want?  Probably not.

Comment: I got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$(x)!!=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(2n-\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right)^{\frac{x+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}{2}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}{2k+x}$$Let $b(x)$ be Brian's continuation and $k(x)$ be mine. Then for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Z}^-$, $|k(x)|\ge|b(x)|$. I.e. our continuations aren't the same except in the positive integers.